# Why is focus deprecated on HTMLSelectElement?

Tags: html, standards, deprecated, w3c, html-select

According to [MDN HTMLSelectElement reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Method_overview), `focus` and `blur` methods are being deprecated since HTML5. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `focus` and `blur` methods have been moved to the [HTMLElement interface](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#htmlelement) from which the HTMLSelectElement interface derives.

This makes sense, since any element that has a `tabindex` attribute can gain and lose focus, not just specialised elements as may have been the case when [DOM Level 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980) was written.